# C# web application MessageBox.Show issue

Tags: c#, messagebox, msgbox

I have a switch statement that iterates through the buttons in my html and names them.  I would like to display a message box as the default case, but when i try to create the MessageBox it displays an error.  I tried using System.Windows.Forms; but when I implement that I cant pass information to my buttonsetup function.  I realized using System.Windows.Forms; is only for console applications.  Do I need to go into the html and make a message?  if so, how and how do i implement it properly.

```
EX:
case 38:
    ButtonSetup(dr, this.Button39);
    break;
case 39:
    ButtonSetup(dr, this.Button40);
    break;
default:
    MessageBox.Show("There are more tblBldgs records than buttons on Bldgs.aspx.");
    break;
```

Comment: MessageBox is a windows form control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand the difference between server-side logic (C# in this case) and client side logic (JavaScript). If you want to show a "message box" on the client, you'll need the server side to tell the client side.

This could be done by having the server write out a JavaScript alert.

This is the JavaScript you ultimately need on your page:

```
alert("There are more....");
```

That being said, I suspect you're just trying to indicate that message to the user. Using a pop-up is a bad idea here. What I would do is use your default case to show an HTML message on the page to the user. They'll still see it, but it won't be so intrusive.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [**Javascript Popup Box**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

You cannot mix Windows Forms with ASP.NET (web forms)

Other than that, you are mixing Console Applications with Windows Forms Applications and ASP.NET. (3 different things).

**A console application** is an application that takes input and displays output at a command line console with access to three basic data streams: standard input, standard output and standard error. A console application facilitates the reading and writing of characters from a console - either individually or as an entire line. It is the simplest form of a C# program and is typically invoked from the Windows command prompt. A console application usually exists in the form of a stand-alone executable file with minimal or no graphical user interface (GUI).

**Windows Forms** is a set of managed libraries in .NET Framework designed to develop rich client applications. It is a graphical API to display data and manage user interactions with easier deployment and better security in client applications. Windows Forms offers an extensive client library providing interface to access native Windows graphical interface elements and graphics from managed code. It is built with event-driven architecture similar to Windows clients and hence, its applications wait for user input for its execution.

**ASP.NET** works with the Internet Information Server (IIS) to deliver the content in response to client requests. While processing the requests, ASP.NET provides access to all .NET classes, custom components and databases, similar to that of a desktop application.

**Web forms** are the building blocks of application development in ASP.NET. They provide lot of flexibility by allowing controls to be used on a page as objects. These controls can handle events such as Load, Click and Change, similar to those in desktop applications. Other than Web forms, ASP.NET can be used to create XML Web services that can allow building modular, distributed web applications, written in any language.These services are interoperable across variety of platforms and devices.